# how to exclude admin user from my user list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

how to exclude admin users from my user list? the below image shows the problem. I don't want to show the admin user in the friend list of a user.

[image]

I don't want to show the main_admin user on this user list as it is my admin user of the site

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Profile
from feed.models import Post
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Profile, FriendRequest
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
import random

User = get_user_model()


@login_required
def users_list(request):
    users = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user)
    sent_to = []
    friends = []
    for user in users :
        friend = user.friends.all()
        for f in friend:
            if f in friends:
                friend = friend.exclude(user=f.user)
        friends += friend
    my_friends = request.user.profile.friends.all()
    for i in my_friends:
        if i in friends:
            friends.remove(i)
    if request.user.profile in friends:
        friends.remove(request.user.profile)
    random_list = random.sample(list(users), min(len(list(users)), 10))
    for r in random_list:
        if r in friends:
            random_list.remove(r)
    friends += random_list
    for i in my_friends:
        if i in friends:
            friends.remove(i)
    for se in sent_friend_requests:
        sent_to.append(se.to_user)
    context = {
        'users': friends,
        'sent': sent_to
    }
    return render(request, "users/users_list.html", context)


# def queryset(self, request):
#     if  request.user.is_superuser:
#         return User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False)
#     return User.objects.all()



def friend_list(request):
    p = request.user.profile
    friends = p.friends.all()
    context = {
        'friends': friends
    }
    return render(request, "users/friend_list.html", context)


@login_required
def send_friend_request(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest, created = FriendRequest.objects.get_or_create(
        from_user=request.user,
        to_user=user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(user.profile.slug))


@login_required
def cancel_friend_request(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(
        from_user=request.user,
        to_user=user).first()
    frequest.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(user.profile.slug))


@login_required
def accept_friend_request(request, id):
    from_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=from_user, to_user=request.user).first()
    user1 = frequest.to_user
    user2 = from_user
    user1.profile.friends.add(user2.profile)
    user2.profile.friends.add(user1.profile)
    if FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=from_user).first():
        request_rev = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, to_user=from_user).first()
        request_rev.delete()
    frequest.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(request.user.profile.slug))


@login_required
def delete_friend_request(request, id):
    from_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    frequest = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=from_user, to_user=request.user).first()
    frequest.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(request.user.profile.slug))


def delete_friend(request, id):
    user_profile = request.user.profile
    friend_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=id)
    user_profile.friends.remove(friend_profile)
    friend_profile.friends.remove(user_profile)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/users/{}'.format(friend_profile.slug))


@login_required
def profile_view(request, slug):
    p = Profile.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    u = p.user
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=p.user)
    rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=p.user)
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_name=u)

    friends = p.friends.all()

    # is this user our friend
    button_status = 'none'
    if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all():
        button_status = 'not_friend'

        # if we have sent him a friend request
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=p.user)) == 1:
            button_status = 'friend_request_sent'

        # if we have recieved a friend request
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
            button_status = 'friend_request_received'

    context = {
        'u': u,
        'button_status': button_status,
        'friends_list': friends,
        'sent_friend_requests': sent_friend_requests,
        'rec_friend_requests': rec_friend_requests,
        'post_count': user_posts.count
    }

    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You can now login!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('my_profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/edit_profile.html', context)


@login_required
def my_profile(request):
    p = request.user.profile
    you = p.user
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=you)
    rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=you)
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_name=you)
    friends = p.friends.all()

    # is this user our friend
    button_status = 'none'
    if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all():
        button_status = 'not_friend'

        # if we have sent him a friend request
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=you)) == 1:
            button_status = 'friend_request_sent'

        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
            button_status = 'friend_request_received'

    context = {
        'u': you,
        'button_status': button_status,
        'friends_list': friends,
        'sent_friend_requests': sent_friend_requests,
        'rec_friend_requests': rec_friend_requests,
        'post_count': user_posts.count
    }

    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)


@login_required
def search_users(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    object_list = User.objects.filter(username__icontains=query)
    context = {
        'users': object_list
    }
    return render(request, "users/search_users.html", context)
```

> Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
from autoslug import AutoSlugField


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Profile", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/{}".format(self.slug)


def post_save_user_model_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        except:
            pass


post_save.connect(post_save_user_model_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='to_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='from_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "From {}, to {}".format(self.from_user.username, self.to_user.username)
```

Here as you can see main_admin is my superuser and I don't want it to appear in the add new friend list, so please help me out to solve this problem as I'm new to django, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just have to exclude the admin from the returned friends list :

```
def friend_list(request):
    p = request.user.profile
    friends = p.friends.exclude(user__is_staff=True)
    context = {
        'friends': friends
    }
return render(request, "users/friend_list.html", context)
```

Comment: FieldError at /friends/

Cannot resolve keyword 'is_staff' into field. Choices are: bio, friends, id, image, profile, slug, user, user_id    got this error bro @Rvector

Comment: yet I'm getting the same output

Comment: Can you show the models ? because the filter needs valid fields to work...

Answer (score 0):

```
p.friends.all().exclude(is_superuser=True)
```

Make sure your user class parameter is using `(AbstractUser)`.

Comment: no bro its not working for me

Comment: Please share your User model.

Comment: I have updated my answer.